# Create Cocoapod using GoogleAnalytics (a cocoapod), Unable to pass validation

Tags: ios, swift, validation, google-analytics, cocoapods

**Goal** : Create a cocoapod using 'Google/Analytics' (swift)
**Problem** : Unable to pass validation after executing   : `pod repo push MyCocoapods MyCocoapods.podspec`

MyCocoapods.podspec :

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name         = "MyCocoapods"
  s.version      = "0.1.1"
  s.summary      = "MyCocoapods, checker"
  s.description  = "Think: What does it do? Why did you write it? What is the focus?"
  s.homepage     = "http://www.jeuxvideo.com"
  s.license      = { :type => "MIT", :file => "LICENSE" }
  s.author             = { "John Dow" => "john.doe@gmail.com" }
  s.platform     = :ios
  s.ios.deployment_target = "8.0"
  s.source       = { :git => "git@bitbucket.org:dokidocu/mycocoapods.git", :tag => "#{s.version}" }
  s.source_files  = "MyCocoapods/**/*.{swift}"
  s.framework  = "Foundation"
  s.requires_arc = true
  s.dependency 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 2.3'
  s.dependency 'Google/Analytics'

end
```

When I execute : `pod repo push MyCocoapods MyCocoapods.podspec --verbose`

I get this error :

> - ERROR | [iOS] unknown: Encountered an unknown error (The 'Pods' target has transitive dependencies that include static binaries:
>     (/private/var/folders/_s/8bj_jrf143nd21dmhqxz16m40000gn/T/CocoaPods/Lint/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLAnalytics.a
>     and
>     /private/var/folders/_s/8bj_jrf143nd21dmhqxz16m40000gn/T/CocoaPods/Lint/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a))
>     during validation.

**Any ideas of how to make it works ?**

(If I remove 'Google/Analytics' from the dependency and the Podfile, the pod can be validated... but that's not what I want"

Comment: Have you tried using `pod spec lint <PodSpecName>.podspec --verbose --use-libraries`